# User migration from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate databases and users from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 8.0. Starting with MySQL 8 we can no longer (implicitly) create a user using the GRANT command. Need to use CREATE USER instead, followed by the GRANT statement. But the challenge with this method is, it doesn’t take encrypted password while creating a user.

I have a long list of users and need to migrate them with their existing passwords and privileges. Any suggestion would be of great help!

Comment: Upgrading to the latest release is recommended before upgrading to the next version. For example, upgrade to the latest MySQL 5.7 release before upgrading to MySQL 8.0.   you sould first update to a 5.7 version and read also there the upgrade instructions which are very good see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html

Comment: You can still add MySQL 8 users with password hashes. You may need to specify the encryption schema though (as the default changed). You should specify/clarify your problem/error messages/what you tried and didn't work as expected (e.g. the query you ran/the dump that couldnt be imported/...)